Correct configuration of paths in vue 3 router
I have a router file that contains links to pages (I think it makes no sense to attach it, there are no errors)
There is a films component.vue, in which I display a list of films for the swiper as cards (links like)
And I need that when clicking on this card, a page opens specifically for a specific card (the data for the card is in the array that I take from firebase), but I have no idea how to configure the paths so that it works.
Maybe someone has encountered:
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
const router = useRouter();
const selectFilm = (film) => {
    router.push('/films-info');
};
defineProps({
    films: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
        default: () => []
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    link: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
    imgUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
    imgAlt: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
})
</script>
<template>
    <div class="swiper__container">
        <h1 class="swiper__title">{{ title }}</h1>
        <swiper-container class="swiper" :slides-per-view="5" :space-between="20">
            <swiper-slide v-for="(film, index) in films" :key="index" class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="swiper-slide__container" @click="selectFilm(film)">
                    <img class="swiper__img" :src="film.imgUrl" :alt="film.imgAlt">
                    <!-- <RouterLink to="/films-info" class="swiper-link">{{ film.link }}</RouterLink> -->
                    <a class="swiper-link">{{ film.link }}</a>
                </div>
            </swiper-slide>
        </swiper-container>
    </div>
</template>

and here is the array from which I get the data for the cards:
const fetchMovies = async () => {
    try {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(filmsRef);
        const moviesData = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
            link: doc.data().title,
            imgUrl: doc.data().img,
            imgAlt: doc.data().alt,
            status: doc.data().status,
        }));
        movies.value = moviesData;
        console.log(moviesData);
        loader.value = false;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching movies:', error);
    }
};

But how to make the page open for a specific card and output data only for it, I do not understand at all. Help please..
I have tried very little, because this is the first time I have faced such a task.

You've not shown what component /films-info leads to, so it's not known how or what initial data is required to be sent to the component to then load the correct film data.  You probably want to add a param to the route, such as a film id, that your component can then access via useRoute().params to then fetch some specific film data.

Yes, I have already solved the problem. I'll attach the solution later :)
